# Discord.js - How do I convert user ID to Member

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am wondering how to convert an ID to a Member. The ID I want to convert is in a .JSON file. I have this script:

```
if(message.content == "!fl leaderboard") {
        embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        const c = Object.entries(db).sort((a, b)=> b[1].level - a[1].level)
        for(const [key, value] of c) {
            embed.addField(db[message.author.id].tag, `Level: ${value.level} | XP: ${value.xp}`)
        }
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
```

And this is what it posts: [image]

The script of the level system is: https://hastebin.com/epucihenin.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const User = client.users.cache.get("userid");
if (!User) return console.error("Couldn't find the user"); // Note that the user must be in a Guild with your bot for this to work.

console.log(`I found the user ${User.username}.`);
```

Comment: Where do I put it?

Comment: You'll have to replace the "userid" with the data from the database in your loop.

Comment: my database only has {

}

Comment: Can u get me on dms? my discord is: kief#5555

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having trouble understanding that. What does `{ }` mean? Does your database have an empty Object?

Comment: Hi, My data base has: {}  so inside it stores the [id][level][xp] for the users nothing else is in it. So this is why I am confused on where to put it

Comment: also here it the .json file: https://hastebin.com/okedejequc.py

Comment: Does [this](https://hastebin.com/obecoxixav.js) fix your issue?

Comment: wait never mind I put it in the index.js and testing it rn

Comment: Hi, 1. it works but after I see the leaderboard; I type then it post the leaderboard again and again. it is also only posting level one

Comment: I have resloved the level issue

Comment: hi, it keeps sending messages after I do the command then type.

Comment: the "Does this fix your issue?" comment link dosnt work anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can use `guild.member()` to get a member object from a user object, and you can use `client.users.fetch()` to get a user object from an ID.

[.member()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member)

[.fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch)